# Run docker-compose over ssh call trough gitlab CI/CD to amazon linux AMI EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've just spend so much time to found out the answer to my question by myself and it was kinda simple but i would like to know if anyone can explain me why it worked only like the following.

To resume I wanted to run a docker-compose over an ssh command from gitlab ci cd runner to my amazon ec2 ami and only the following command worked =>

```
ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i $sshKey $user@$host 'docker-compose -v'
```

I've tried with double quote : `ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i $sshKey $user@$host "docker-compose -v"`

no quote :

```
ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i $sshKey $user@$host docker-compose -v
```

and for exemple when i try to run the command under windows terminal i got no issue running it with double quote ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the command interpreter in Windows will behave differently than the bash in Linux.
See "[How to make Windows command prompt treat single quote as though it is a double quote?](https://superuser.com/a/328698/141)"

> In Win32 programs, splitting up the command line into "words" — the NUL-terminated multi-byte character strings that programs in the C and C++ languages see as the argument array passed to `main()` — is the province of the runtime libraries of those programs.
>
> On Unices and Linux, the shell does the word splitting, because the operating system actually works in terms of an argument string array.
> This is not the case for Win32.
>
> On Win32, the operating system itself operates in terms of a command tail: a single long string that still contains all of the quotation marks that one originally typed on the command line.

So in your case, "docker-compose -v" would work on Windows, but no in a Linux bash, as its shell would remove the quotes, and you get two strings, instead of one `docker-compose -v` command.

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply , i'll take a look on the link you've given too , this is kinda annoying i've fallen on article that was talking about not having the good version of docker-compose when this case happen